# Rename-Item : add unique numeric sequence to prevent duplicate file names

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I need a way to rename files in a directory that would result in an error with a simple `Rename-Item`. The files need the same 10 digit code followed by 4 digit place holder (numbers only please).

Current file names:

```
01_img_0028.JPG
01_img_0029.JPG
02_img_0028.JPG
02_img_0029.JPG
```

Considering the files above, renaming the files with a `split` (using the 4 digit in the original name) would fail because there will be files with the same name:

```
B0000000000.0028.JPG
B0000000000.0029.JPG
B0000000000.0028.JPG
B0000000000.0029.JPG
```

Does anyone have an idea to get around this? The 4 digits can be any sequence of numbers but it would be great if we could make the end result look like:

```
B0000000000.0001.JPG
B0000000000.0002.JPG
B0000000000.0003.JPG
B0000000000.0004.JPG
```

Here is my current code that will rename all unique files and the first of duplicates, but error out on files that would then be duplicate names:

```
$jpgToRename = GCI -Path $pathToRename -Filter '*.jpg' -R
foreach ($jpg in $jpgToRename) {
    $splitPath = $jpg.FullName.Split("\\")
    $newName = -join ($splitPath[7], ".", $jpg.BaseName, ".PC_850.jpg")
    Rename-Item $jpg.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a counter here would keep this simple for your need:

```
$jpgToRename = GCI -Path $pathToRename -Filter '*.jpg' -R
$counter = 1
foreach($jpg in $jpgToRename){
    $splitPath = $jpg.FullName.Split("\\")
    $formattedCounter = $counter.ToString("0000")
    $newName =  -Join($splitPath[7], ".",$formattedCounter, $jpg.BaseName, ".PC_850.jpg")
    Rename-Item $jpg.FullName -NewName $newName
    $counter++
}
```